# JIRA 3.13 dashboard show ticket with specific columns

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I am using JIRA 3.13, I want to show list of tickets (based on a certain filter) in the dashboard with a column of my choice. For example, I want to show the ticket name, description, and resolution date (or a column of my choice). Is this possible? I use "Show saved Filter", the one that came with JIRA, but it does not allow me to do any customization.

Does anyone has a solution of how to have this showed in JIRA dashboard? Do I need to install a certain for this? Is it free? How do I install it?

Thanks all for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a paid portlet that we can use to do this. The portlet is called "Jira Show Saved Filter With Columns" made by jPlugs.com. We have to pay ~$200.

Installation is pretty simple but requires to bring down JIRA (restart). Anyway, the steps is:
1. Put the jar file in WEB-INF/lib
2. Restart JIRA

The company offer 30 days trial. In order to get the trial key, you need to create an account in their website and then generate the trial key also from their website. Make sure you check the version of the portlet that you install. For me, I use version 2.03 which looks like the latest that was released for my JIRA.

Hopefully, this info will help others.